# Getting error messages when comparing negative binomial models (glm.nb) using aictab

Tags: r

I have a question regarding comparing negative binomial models on my insect abundance data using AICc values and I got error message saying

```
"Error in aictab.default(cand.set = model15LT_T, second.ord = T, sort = T,  : 
 Function not yet defined for this object class”
```

Here is my code:

```
model15LT_T = list()
model15LT_T[[1]] = glm.nb(TotalN ~ 1+offset(log(Dates)), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[2]] = glm.nb(TotalN ~ PC1_0.5+offset(log(Dates)), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[3]] = glm.nb(TotalN ~ PC2_0.5+offset(log(Dates)), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[4]] = glm.nb(TotalN ~ PC1_0.5 + PC2_0.5+offset(log(Dates)), data=DAT)

aictab(cand.set = model15LT_T, second.ord = T, sort = T, modnames = c("TotalN.1", 
                                                                    "TotalN.pc1.0.5", 
                                                                    "TotalN.pc2.0.5", 
                                                                    "TotalN.pc1+pc2.0.5"))
```

But then when I tried specifying the family in the model instead of using glm.nb as below (I copied and pasted every code except changing the glm.nb to glm (family=negative.binomial (theta=1)) and then the error message went away.

```
model15LT_T = list()
model15LT_T[[1]] = glm(TotalN ~ 1+offset(log(Dates)), family=negative.binomial (theta=1), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[2]] = glm(TotalN ~ PC1_0.5+offset(log(Dates)), family=negative.binomial (theta=1), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[3]] = glm(TotalN ~ PC2_0.5+offset(log(Dates)),family=negative.binomial (theta=1), data=DAT)
model15LT_T[[4]] = glm(TotalN ~ PC1_0.5 + PC2_0.5+offset(log(Dates)), family=negative.binomial (theta=1),data=DAT)

aictab(cand.set = model15LT_T, second.ord = T, sort = T, modnames = c("Total.1",
                                                                                                                    "Total.PC1",
                                                                                                                    "Total.PC2",
                                                                                                                    "Total.PC1+PC2"))
```

My questions are:

1) Does that mean I cannot get aictab to work using glm.nb?

2) If I have to specify theta value in `glm(TotalN~., family=negative.binomial)`, is there a better way to know what value to put?

Answer (score 1):

1) That seems to be the case. You can easily calculate the AIC by hand using e.g. the *twologlik*-slot in the  objects returned by glm.nb()

```
aic1 = 2*(nrow(model15LT_T[[1]]$coef)+1)-model15LT_T[[1]]$twologlik
```

Note that nrow(model15LT_T[[1]]$coef) + 1 = 2 since you estimate 1 regression parameter (the intercept) plus the overdispersion.

2) If you already know theta than you can specify it in this way, but it seems to me that you'd better estimate it unless you have a very good reason to fix it at *1*.  Remember theta is the overdispersion parameter of the negative binomial. It is a nuisance parameter that is needed to estimate the mean of the log-linear regression but you don't want to do inference on.